# Empty Column Showing Zero Empty Values and Not Removable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe with an empty column:

```
my_df <- structure(list(X1 = c("​", "​", "Assets", "Cash", 
"Liability"), X2 = c("​", "​", "​", "​", 
"​"), X4 = c("​", "Uncredited", "21,765", "11,534​", 
"10,738"), X7 = c("​", "Uncredited", "24,627", "​14,412", 
"12,845")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

my_df

     X1            X2          X4            X7
    <chr>         <chr>       <chr>        <chr>
1   ​   ​   
2   ​   ​                 Uncredited    Uncredited
3   Assets  ​   ​           ​21,765           24,627 
4   Cash    ​               11,534        14,412 
5   Liability   ​           10,738        12,845
```

The `str` method shows the column 2 is completely empty. Here it's column 2, but it can be column 3 or column 4 in different dataframes.

```
str(my_df)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X1: chr  "​" "​" "Assets" ...
 $ X2: chr  "​" "​" "​" "​" ...
 $ X4: chr  "​" "Uncredited" "21,765" ...
 $ X7: chr  "​" "Uncredited" "24,627" ...
```

However, if we try to count the empty values in each column, we see 0 empty row for the column 2.

```
colSums(is.na(my_df) | my_df == "")

X1  X2  X4  X7
0   0   1   1
```

Maybe that's the reason, whatever methods I have tried below to remove empty column didn't work.

```
# Using `discard`
my_df %>% discard(~all(is.na(.) | . ==""))

# Using `colSums`
empty_columns <- colSums(is.na(my_df) | my_df == "") == nrow(my_df)
my_df[, !empty_columns]

# Using `sapply`
empty_columns <- sapply(my_df, function(x) all(is.na(x) | x == ""))
my_df[, !empty_columns]
```

What would be the problem with the column 2 -- column number differs sometimes -- and how it can be removed? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your sample data copy/pasteably with `dput()`? `dput(my_df)` would be much nicer than manually entering all the empty strings.

Comment: If you just want to zap column X2, the following should do: `my_df$X2 <- NULL`

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, it's updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that it is not a blank

```
 charToRaw(my_df$X2[1])
[1] e2 80 8b
charToRaw("")
raw(0)
```

We may replace the elements to blank and then do the `select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(textclean)
 my_df %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.character), 
       ~ replace_non_ascii(.x, NA_character_))) %>%
   select(where(~any(complete.cases(.x))))
```

-output

```
       X1         X4         X7
1          ​           ​           ​
2          ​ Uncredited Uncredited
3    Assets     21,765     24,627
4      Cash     11,534​     ​14,412
5 Liability     10,738     12,845
```

Comment: Thanks again @akrun. It makes sense now. Considering the column number changes with different dataframes, how can we approach that?